# Xamarin Forms Custom Cell Currency Format?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom FiancialCell that works, but does not format to currency. Is there another way to change the binding format so that it is $ ?

```
    public FinancialCell()
    {
          .......

        //Set the bindings to the FinancialRow object to be bound to this
        lblTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

        ///Why does this not format to $ when displayed?
        lblValue.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Value", stringFormat: "C");


        this.View = stack;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `"{0:C}"` instead and it will work.

Here is your example, integrated with the fix, just for completeness:-

```
    public FinancialCell()
    {
          .......

        //Set the bindings to the FinancialRow object to be bound to this
        lblTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

        ///Why does this not format to $ when displayed?
        lblValue.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Value", stringFormat: "{0:C}");


        this.View = stack;
    }
```